# For loop inside method of class not running?

Tags: c++

The `for` loop inside the method `myMethod()` isn't running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be initializing `i`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
```

Also, you should definitely learn to use the debugger. Then, you can step through the code. You can see what `i` is, you can see what `n` is, and you can see where the execution path is not what you expected.